# Convert uppercase matches to bold using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, uppercase, bold

i need to find all uppercase words in a string and set it bold

```
$_POST['descricao'] = "UPPERCASE test WORD"
$_POST['descricao'] = preg_replace("\b[A-Z]{2,}\b", "<b>\\1</b>", $_POST['descricao']);
```

it should return: `<b>UPPERCASE</b> test <b>WORD</b>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to capture the group and enclose the pattern:

```
preg_replace("/\b([A-Z]{2,})\b/", "<b>\\1</b>", $_POST['descricao']);
```

Comment: No need to group, `\\0` can also be used for whole match.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller, fair, I like to be explicit.

Comment: thank you it worked.. what about this `$str = "PAREDE BOX"`
it returns `<b>PAREDE</b> <b>BOX</b>` i needed `<b>PAREDE BOX</b>`

Comment: Update your regular expressions to allow for spaces.

Comment: i don't know much about regex how should i do that?

Comment: This will get you started - `([A-Z ]{2,})`. Adjust accordingly or ask another question.

Comment: it returned me `<b>PAREDE BOX </b>teste` and everytime that i send my form it adds another `<b>` like `<b><b>PAREDE BOX </b></b>teste`

Comment: just do simple `str_replace('</b> <b>', ' ', $_POST['descricao']);` after this `preg_replace`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$_POST['descricao'] = "UPPERCASE test WORD"
$_POST['descricao'] = preg_replace("/\b([A-Z]{2,})\b/", "<b>$1</b>", $_POST['descricao']);
```